# VB.Net: "Drag" Formula Down an Excel Column

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-formula, cell, formula

I have the formula...`=IF(D3="Yes",IF(MOD(B3,2)=0,"No Gap","Gap"),"Not 24 Hour")` and am trying to figure out a way to programmatically "Drag" that formula down to "X" number of rows. I know I could make a for loop to do this, but I'm hoping there is an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772659/copying-a-formula-and-applying-it-to-a-new-cell-range) has some answers for copying formulas and dynamically changing the Row/Colmns

Comment: What have you tried? It should be relatively easy to use a range in VB.net, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @BruceWayne the changing of the row(D3) and (B3) to for example (D5) and (B5) wouldn't work with just a range if I'm correct in my reading

Comment: See [Range.FillDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-filldown-method-excel)

Comment: You could use `R1C1` referencing, which would adjust the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the formula is in cell `E3`, just try this simple macro,

```
Sub formula()
Dim i As Long
i = InputBox("Enter number of rows")
Range("E3:E" & i + 2).formula = Range("E3").formula
End Sub
```

This macro prompts for the number of rows to fill the formula, (range E3:E in this example). Hope this helps